# Loss & accuracy don't improve in Xception (image classification)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, google-colaboratory

As a trial, I'm implementing Xception to classify images without using pretrained weight in Tensorflow.
However, the accuracy are too low compared to the original paper.
Could somebody share any advice to address this problem?

I prepared 500 out of 1000 classes from [ImageNet](https://image-net.org/) and train [ready-Xception model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/xception/Xception) with this data from scrach  .
I tried the same learning rate and optimizer as used in [the original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02357.pdf).

> – Optimizer: SGD
> – Momentum: 0.9
> – Initial learning rate: 0.045
> – Learning rate decay: decay of rate 0.94 every 2 epochs

However, this did not work so well.

I know it is better to use all of 1000 classes rather than only 500, however, I couldn't prepare storage for it.
Did it affect the performance of my code?

Here is my code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers, losses, models, optimizers, callbacks, applications, preprocessing

# scheduler
def scheduler(epoch, lr):
    return 0.045*0.94**(epoch/2.0)
lr_decay = callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(scheduler)

# early stopping
EarlyStopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=500, verbose=0, mode='auto', restore_best_weights=True)

# build xception
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
x = tf.cast(inputs, tf.float32)
x = tf.keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input(x) #preprocess image
x = applications.xception.Xception(weights=None, include_top=False,)(x, training=True)
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = layers.Dense(nb_class)(x)
outputs = layers.Softmax()(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.SGD(momentum=0.9, nesterov=True), 
            loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', 
            metrics= ['accuracy'])

# fitting data
history = model.fit(image_gen(df_train_chunk, 224, 224, ), #feed images with a generator
                    batch_size = 32,
                    steps_per_epoch = 64,
                    epochs=1000000000,
                    validation_data = image_gen(df_valid_chunk, 224, 224, ),  #feed images with a generator
                    validation_steps = 64,
                    callbacks = [lr_decay, EarlyStopping],
                    )
```

My results are below. In the original paper, its accuracy reached around 0.8.
In contrast, the performance of my code is too poor.
[image: here]
[image: here]

## P.S.

Some might wonder if my generator got wrong, so I put my generator code and result below.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageOps

def image_gen(df_data, h, w, shuffle=True):
    nb_class = len(np.unique(df_data['Class']))
    while True:
        if shuffle:
            df_data = df_data.sample(frac=1) 
        for i in range(len(df_data)):
            X = Image.open((df_data.iloc[i]).loc['Path'])
            X = X.convert('RGB')
            X = X.resize((w,h))
            X = preprocessing.image.img_to_array(X)
            X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=0)
            
            klass = (df_data.iloc[i]).loc['Class']
            y = np.zeros(nb_class)
            y[klass] = 1
            y = np.expand_dims(y, axis=0)

            yield X, y

train_gen = image_gen(df_train_chunk, 224, 224, )

for i in range(5):
    X, y = next(train_gen)
    print('\n\n class: ', y.argmax(-1))
    display(Image.fromarray(X.squeeze(0).astype(np.uint8)))
```

the result is below.
[image: pic]

Answer (score 0):

When you chose only 500 labels, do you choose the first 500?
softmax output starting from 0, so make sure your labels staring from 0 to 499 either.

Comment: I have checked if the generator that feed images and labels works correctly. Each image correspond with each label.